# Aggregation and grouping

Tags: haskell

For example:

`db = [(1,20),(1,12),(1,28),(2,13),(2,37),(4,11),(4,4),(4,5),(4,10)]` is given.

the result:

```
groupandagg db (+) [(1,60),(2,50),(4,30)]
```

We must get the following list through a function at fist:

```
[ (1[201228]) (2[1337]) (4[114510]) ]
```

I have finished the first program:

```
main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing

makekgrl :: [(Int,Int)]->[(Int,[Int])]
makekgrl []= []
makekgrl (a,c):[] = [(a,c)]
makekgrl ((a,c):(b,d):_)
     | a==b  = makekgrl ([(a,c:d:[]):_)
     | otherwiese = (a,c):makekgrl((b,d):_)
```

But one error occurred in this line:

```
 makekgrl []= []
```

the error

```
E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:8:13: error:
    parse error on input `='
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
  |
8 |  makekgrl []= []

  |             ^
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

I do have two questions:

1. Why did the error occur?
2. How to use the program i have finished to get the result in the very above?

after correction:

```
main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing

--the second primnumer Function from leture


makekgrl :: [(Int,Int)]->[(Int,[Int])]
makekgrl [] = []
makekgrl [(a,c)] = [(a,c)]
makekgrl ((a,c):(b,d):_)
    |a==b = makekgrl ((a,c:d:[]):_)
    |otherwiese = [(a,c)] ++ makekgrl((b,d):_)
```

error

```
E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:11:34: error:
    * Found hole: _ :: [(Int, [Int])]
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `_'
      In the first argument of `makekgrl', namely `((a, c : d : []) : _)'
      In the expression: makekgrl ((a, c : d : []) : _)
    * Relevant bindings include
        d :: Int
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:10:20)
        b :: Int
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:10:18)
        c :: Int
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:10:14)
        a :: Int
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:10:12)
        makekgrl :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, [Int])]
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:8:1)
      Valid hole fits include
        mempty :: forall a. Monoid a => a
          with mempty @[(Int, [Int])]
          (imported from `Prelude' at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in `GHC.Base'))
   |
11 |     |a==b = makekgrl ((a,c:d:[]):_)

   |                                  ^

E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:12:6: error:
    * Variable not in scope: otherwiese :: Bool
    * Perhaps you meant `otherwise' (imported from Prelude)
   |
12 |     |otherwiese = [(a,c)] ++ makekgrl((b,d):_)

   |      ^^^^^^^^^^

E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:12:45: error:
    * Found hole: _ :: [(Int, Int)]
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `_'
      In the first argument of `makekgrl', namely `((b, d) : _)'
      In the second argument of `(++)', namely `makekgrl ((b, d) : _)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        d :: Int
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:10:20)
        b :: Int
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:10:18)
        c :: Int
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:10:14)
        a :: Int
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:10:12)
        makekgrl :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, [Int])]
          (bound at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:8:1)
      Valid hole fits include
        mempty :: forall a. Monoid a => a
          with mempty @[(Int, Int)]
          (imported from `Prelude' at E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_1_(from_reddit).hs:1:1
           (and originally defined in `GHC.Base'))
   |
12 |     |otherwiese = [(a,c)] ++ makekgrl((b,d):_)

   |                                             ^
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

Comment: 1. The error occurs because you need a space before the `=`, it's parsing `[]=` as a single unit. 2) You should also demonstrate some effort at the aggregation yourself.

Comment: @A Tayler the same error occured ...Haskell is really difficult

Comment: I fixed up some of the code layout to be more consistent. However, there may be actual code indentation problems that are causing your errors. Read up on Haskell indentation rules.

Comment: @ Bob Dalgleish I have corrected the program. Aber there are more errors...

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped you, the same with all your other questions

Answer (score 2):

`_` on the left hand side of `=` definitions is a *wild card*,  part of a pattern. It matches anything and remembers nothing.

`_` on the right hand side of `=` definitions does not denote a value; it is a signal to compiler "I don't have anything, just want to see what type should go there!".

And this is what the compiler is telling you. It's not so much an error, as it is a message:

```
    * Found hole: _ :: [(Int, [Int])]
```

I.e. you need to put there something with the above type (`::` is read: "has type").

This `_` is known as a *typed hole*. Each `_` is different, unique. They are used in *type-driven development*.

Comment: @dfeuer thanks for the edit! (I wanted more eyeballs and so was delaying  doing it myself... theory being, when ppl see "modified" next to my name they are less inclined to check it out :) ).